# Why is Rails not caching SQL queries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

According to the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching):

> Query caching is a Rails feature that caches the result set returned
>   by each query so that if Rails encounters the same query again for
>   that request, it will use the cached result set as opposed to running
>   the query against the database again.

Then follows an example where the same query is executed within a controller's action:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # Run a find query
    @products = Product.all

    ...

    # Run the same query again
    @products = Product.all
  end

end
```

In my view layout at several places I call `Category.pluck(:id)`. In the development log I then see this line several times:

```
SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories"
```

This happens even if I set this: `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` for development. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query cache come from Rack.

Run `rake middleware`

And look for `ActiveRecord::QueryCache`

If thats in your middleware, SQL caching should be enabled, unless something else is turning it off.

Here is some documentation on the query cache:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html

And the Rack code

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryCache.html